# Places where properties (ivars) may be first initialized?

Tags: objective-c, properties, initialization

I asked a related question earlier but I am specifically wondering about the opportunities one has to initialize an ivar declared as a property. I realise you can initialize it via a call to alloc and a form of init, or do the initialization in the getter through lazy instantiation.

Where else might you want to initialize a property, and does there always have to be an `alloc` of sorts to do so, as there is with initializing an instance? (I realise a property is not an object, I am just struggling with how it comes into being to be used by an instance of a class).

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You gave the two best options. Initialize in one ore more `init...` methods, or use lazy initialization in the getter.

Comment: Hey, thanks for response @rmaddy, good to know I have that right. Is it the case then that an alloc will always be needed to carry out the initialization of an ivar, yes? Just want to be certain.

Comment: Initializing an ivar first requires that an instance of the class it belongs to be created first. So essentially yes, you must first alloc (and init) the instance. Then you can initialize (at any future time) an ivar of that class instance.

Comment: but the alloc and init is required for the ivars also to be initialised, yes? even after instance of class has been created? or when the class is created are they automatically initialised to something? just not clear on those two things .. what happens to properties upon instance creation, and if you need an alloc and init sequence for properties after instance of class created. thanks a lot!

Comment: It depends. If the value is passed into the `init...` method, you don't need to alloc/init the ivar. If the ivar is a primitive type then of course you don't need to use alloc/init. You should really update your question with specific examples you are struggling with. Then someone can provide a proper answer.

Comment: hey no, that's great. Between your help and other questions I asked, I've got it now. Thanks a lot for your help!